# Send bash array to json file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I pulled some config variables from a json file with jq.
And once modified, i want to write the whole config array (which can contain keys that were not there at first) to the json file.
The "foreach" part seems quite obvious.
But how to express "change keyA by value A or add keyA=>valueA" to the conf file ?
I'm stuck with something like

```
for key in "${!conf[@]}"; do
    value=${conf[$key]}
    echo $key $value
    jq --arg key $key --arg value $value '.$key = $value' $conf_file > $new_file
done
```

Thanks

Comment: what's your `$conf_file` contents?

Comment: We need to see 1 small record and your expected change. Also, `'.$key = $value'` will be the string literal `'.$key = $value'` and the vars will not expand their values. Good luck.

Comment: My conf file is something like
`
    {
    "status": "running",
    "minFrom": "2018-01-23",
    "maxTo": "2018-01-24",
    "nextTo": "2018-01-23",
    "nextFrom": "2018-01-22"
    }
`
I just managed some partial solution with this code in the loop
`
     jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '.[$key] = $value' $conf_file > $conf_temp_file && mv $conf_temp_file $conf_file
`
but it's really not fine, since it's reading/writing the conf file once per field.

Comment: (Sorry for code formatting, not easy in comments)

Comment: @MarvinLeRouge Then why put in comment `;-)` Put that in code please

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution with single **`jq`** invocation:

Sample `conf` array:

```
declare -A conf=([status]="finished" [nextTo]="2018-01-24" [result]=true)
```

Sample file `conf.json`:

```
{
  "status": "running",
  "minFrom": "2018-01-23",
  "maxTo": "2018-01-24",
  "nextTo": "2018-01-23",
  "nextFrom": "2018-01-22"
}
```

---

Processing:

```
jq --arg data "$(paste -d':' <(printf "%s\n" "${!conf[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${conf[@]}"))" \
   '. as $conf | map($data | split("\n")[] 
    | split(":") | {(.[0]) : .[1]}) 
    | add | $conf + .' conf.json > conf.tmp && mv conf.tmp conf.json
```

---

The resulting `conf.json` contents:

```
{
  "status": "finished",
  "minFrom": "2018-01-23",
  "maxTo": "2018-01-24",
  "nextTo": "2018-01-24",
  "nextFrom": "2018-01-22",
  "result": "true"
}
```

Comment: In case the keys or values might contain a colon, it would be advisable to use a tab as the separator character.

Answer (score 0):

I finally run into the following solution : not as compact as RomanPerekhrest, but a bit more human-readable. Thanks.

```
function update_conf() {
  echo update_conf
  if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]; then
    conf[$1]=$2
  fi
  for key in "${!conf[@]}"; do
    value=${conf[$key]}
    jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '.[$key] = $value' $confFile > $confTempFile && mv $confTempFile $confF$
  done
}
```